# Common format to convert date formats

Tags: java

I need a common format to convert dates in

1. 2023-12-10
2. 2023-12-10T00:00:00.000
3. 2023-12-10T00:00:00.000000

I am trying with

```
public statc void main(String[] a) {
  convert("2023-12-10");
  convert("2023-12-10T00:00:00.000");
  convert("2023-12-10T00:00:00.000000");
}

private static void convert(String date){
  try {
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(date));
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(date,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS"));
  }
}
```

I am getting the below error

```
"java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2023-12-10T00:00:00.000' could not be parsed at index 20"
```

Please assist

Comment: You can try replacing `LocalDate.parse(date,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS"));` with `LocalDateTime.parse(date);`.

Comment: it does not work

Comment: You need to use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` instead of a pattern (I don't have time to build an answer right now, maybe tomorrow).

Answer (score 1):

## Substring

If you want only date, [pull the first ten](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) characters.

```
String datePortion = input.substring( 0 , 10 );
```

Make a `LocalDate` object.

```java
LocalDate.parse( datePortion ) ;
```

## Parsing

Test for length of string. If ten characters, parse as a `LocalDate`. If longer, parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

No need to specify any formatting patterns. Your inputs comply with the ISO 8601 standard used by default when parsing/generating text.

```
if ( input.length() == 10 ) 
{
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
    …
}
else
{
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
    …
}
```

[As Commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105800/common-format-to-convert-date-formats/78106206?noredirect=1#comment137699446_78106206), if you want only the date portion, we can collapse that code to a one-liner using a [ternary statement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator).

```java
LocalDate ld = input.length() == 10 ? LocalDate.parse( input ) : LocalDateTime.parse( input ).toLocalDate() ;
```

Comment: Or, derived from that, if the OP only wants dates: `LocalDate ld = input.length() == 10? LocalDate.parse(input): LocalDateTime.parse(input).toLocalDate();`

Comment: It must be said, of course, that `DateTimeFormatter` supports optional elements directly in the API itself

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Rotteveel says, you can use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, but this is what I was getting at in my comment above, which is a variant:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TimeOrNoTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] dtimes = {
            "2023-12-10",
            "2023-12-10T00:00:00.000",
            "2023-12-10T00:00:00.000011"
        };
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOptionals = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd['T'HH:mm:ss.A]");
        for(String s : dtimes) {
            TemporalAccessor t = dtfOptionals.parseBest(s, LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from);
            System.out.println(t.getClass());
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
}
```